# Non remote methods in remote object implementation

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-system

I am working on a distributed version (rmi) of the game Battleship for school. In the game, each player has a fleet and a grid, so I wanted to be able to use iterators to write code as such

```java
class Fleet implements Iterable<Ship> {

    private List<Ship> fleet;
    ...
    @Override
    public Iterator<Ship> iterator() { return fleet.iterator(); }
}

class Player {

    private Fleet fleet;
    ...
    public void placeFleet() {
        for (Ship s : fleet) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But my class `Fleet` also needs to be a remote class, so I have something like this

```java
interface IFleet extends Remote, Iterable<IShip> {...}

class Fleet extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IFleet {...}
```

However, this causes an error because the `iterator()` method is not a remote method, i.e. I get `illegal remote method encountered: public abstract java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()`

I've also tried with

```java
interface IFleet extends Remote {...}

class Fleet extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IFleet, Iterable<IShip> {...}
```

---

And so I have two questions :

1. Can a remote object implement Remote and its subinterfaces only?
2. Can I somehow hide methods in remote objects from the rmi client (make them unavailable and thus allow them **NOT** to respect the Remote interface needs)?

Thank you!

Ps: I know I can use an iterator over the list in the client in some other way, but this error just made me wonder if it is possible to implement other interfaces along with Remote.

Comment: `Iterable<T>` is an interface did you mean `implements` instead of `extends`?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I got that wrong in the second bit of code

Answer (score 1):

```
implements Remote
```

This is already wrong. You have to define your own remote interface, that *extends* `Remote`, and implement *that*. I suspect this is causing the  problem. You don't have any actual remote methods in your class at all. And as a matter of fact `UnicastRemoteObject` already implements `Remote`.

The answers to your questions are:

1. The remote object can implement whatever interfaces it likes, whether remote or otherwise.
2. They are already hidden if they don't appear in your remote interface.

Your code doesn't make sense unless `Player` is a local object at the server end. Is that the case.

**EDIT** Your edit is also wrong:

```
interface IFleet extends Remote, Iterable<IShip> {...}

class Fleet extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IFleet {...}
```

A remote interface can only contain remote methods, and they must be declared to throw `RemoteException`, and that is the reason for the error message you got: the method(s) of `Iterable` don't throw `RemoteException`.

So, your remote interface must extend `Remote`, and *not* extend `Iterable`. It doesn't make sense anyway if you want to hide that from the client. It is the remote *object* that must *implement* `Iterable`.

> I've also tried with

```
interface IFleet extends Remote {...}

class Fleet extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IFleet, Iterable<IShip> {...}
```

This is the only thing you should ever have tried. It works, and it satisfies your question (2).

Comment: Nope, sorry, I wrote it like that just to simplify (I thought you would understand, I'll change it). I actually have IFleet and IPlayer interfaces both extending Remote and IFleet also extending Iterable<Ship>. It has nothing to do with that. And when I implement a method which is not declared in the remote interface, I get an runtime error (like the one I showed).

Comment: Well that's also wrong: see edit. Nobody will understand if you don't post the real code.